# Prove $(\alpha_1 + ........ + \alpha_n)^2 ≤ n \cdot (\alpha_1^2 + ....... + \alpha_n^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

For any real numbers $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . . . ., \alpha_n$,

$$(\alpha_1 + ...... + \alpha_n)^2 ≤ n \cdot (\alpha_1^2 + ..... + \alpha_n^2)$$

And when is the inequality strict?

Comment: *Hint:* Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ and $(1, ..., 1)$.

Comment: @SimonS it may be a dumm question but isnt Cauchy-Schwarz can only be applied in vectors?

Comment: Yes. And yet, the inner product and the norm on $\mathbb R^n$ are real numbers. Think about my clue and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: you can prove it using induction and only $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$

Comment: @SimonS Still dont get it! Sorry..

Comment: @Elaqqad What do you mean by "only 2ab ≤$ a^2 + b^2$"

Comment: *One more hint:* Writing $a$ for $\alpha$,

$$(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2 = (1 \cdot a_1 + 1 \cdot a_2 + \cdots + 1 \cdot a_n)^2$$

Comment: @mdflas I mean using only the inequality $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ by induction you can prove your statement

Comment: It is equality when $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$, so strict when it's not

Comment: @barto "it's strict when the previous does not hold" is that better?

Comment: @SimonS I tried.. but can't get to the point.. Sorry.

Comment: The inner product of $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ and $(1, \cdots, 1)$ is

$$\langle (a_1, \cdots, a_n), (1, \cdots, 1)\rangle = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$$

See what to do now? By Cauchy-Schwartz,

$$\langle (a_1, \cdots, a_n), (1, \cdots, 1)\rangle \leq \ ||(a_1, \cdots, a_n) || \ || (1, \cdots, 1)|| = \ \cdots$$

Comment: @SimonS Genius!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is just an application of Jensen's inequality. As $f(x) = x^2$ is a convex function, we can apply it here.

Reference : [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#Finite_form)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is to use Titu's Lemma which is also known as Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in Engel form.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\alpha_i^2}{1}\geq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n1}=\frac{(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\ldots+\alpha_n)^2}{n}\\ \implies n({\alpha_1^2 + … + \alpha_n^2})\geq (\alpha_1 + … + \alpha_n)^2\\ \implies (\alpha_1 + … + \alpha_n)^2\leq n({\alpha_1^2 + … + \alpha_n^2})$$

Equality holds iff $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n$

Comment: They don't have to equal n

Comment: @wowlolbrommer, ah yes, sorry for that!

Comment: If he's struggling with C-S, this probably isn't very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's just
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2\geq0.$$
Done!